# C Program. Sorting algorithm does not work in command prompt/terminal

Tags: c, sorting, terminal

I am trying to sort an array of integers, in C, that are randomly typed by the user. If I hard code the array and output it in the IDE, it works perfectly! But when I try and run it in the command prompt, it does not work correctly.

If I type in the command prompt: 12 11 7 5 3, the output is 12 12 12 12 12 when it should be 3 5 7 11 12. I am new to C and am trying figure out how to use it in the command prompt. Any help or guidance in the right direction will be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size = 100;
    int arr[size];
    int i, temp;

    size = argc - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);

        // Bubble Sort
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<(size-i-1);j++)
            { 
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];      //
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];  //  swap
                    arr[j+1] = temp;    //
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running the program? Can you show your command line?

Comment: After setting values in the array, then sort it.

Comment: fix like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j7qCvqefnCcFx0BE)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for your help! I knew it was something small. Worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting sorting before you read all the inputs

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  arr[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
  // sorting
```

Should be

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  arr[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
}
 // Sorting
```

Comment: I put the sorting algorithm outside of the for loop, but it did not work correctly. In the terminal, I type 6 5 4 and I get 7667820 for some reason rather than 4 5 6. I think it has something to do with my printf() statement after the sorting algorithm. printf("%d ", arr[i]); 7667820 only appears when I do this. I do not know why though.

Comment: @legoniko Have you tried the link destination code of my comment?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It just appeared at my on my page and it works Perfectly! Thank you for your help!